# Bean is always null when using @TestConfiguration in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I am using a simple TestConfiguration call in my application to initialize a service bean within the test class:

```
    @TestConfiguration
    static class UserServiceConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public UserService userService() {
            return new UserServiceImpl() {

            };
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
```

When I try running any tests within the class, I immediately get a "this.userService is null" error and the test fails out with a null pointer exception.

I've tried some different fixes, including:

- Putting the TestConfiguration in its own class and importing it via the @Import annotation
- Adding @Primary to the bean as well as giving it a unique name in the @Bean annotation.

A breakpoint in the TestConfiguration return is not called, so it appears as if the service is not being automatically wired to that version.

Note I am new to unit testing in Spring boot and our application is a few years old with various configurations in different places. I am wondering if something else is interfering with the TestConfiguration, but my understanding was that it was supposed to override the service and ignore those configurations? I just cannot figure out why it is not being called.

I am using Spring Boot 2.5.4, Java 18.

Complete code of Test Class:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import com.evotext.user.service.UserService;
import com.evotext.user.service.UserServiceImpl;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class UserServiceConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public UserService userService() {
            return new UserServiceImpl() {

            };
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    
    
    @Test
    public void getCurrentUserSession() {
        
        long l = userService.countTotalUsers();
        assertThat(l == 1);
    }
    
}
```

The service class itself is an interface and the implemented version is annotated with @Service and @Transactional, no name is specified.

Comment: The first problem I see is that you aren't using `@SpringBootTest`. I also note that you're using Jupiter (JUnit 5) but pulling in a JUnit 4 runner; I don't know whether this is a problem since I use Spock.

Comment: I popped @SpringBootTest in there a few times, with and without the runner and still had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get this to work, but since the end goal was to make a test that didn't bring in my full Spring configuration, I did find a work around:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private UserDao userDao;
    
    @InjectMocks
    private UserServiceImpl userService;

   //Your tests and what not
}
```

Check out this [tutorial](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/testing/spring-boot-mockito-junit-example/) for a better detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

use org.junit.Test, NOT org.junit.jupiter.api.Test.

```java
import org.junit.Test;
//import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```